# Teamviewer Server's IP address range

Tags: networking

I want to lock down a computer to only allow teamviewer remote access while not allowing any other internet access. The thought is to set up outbound firewall rules to only allow Teamviewer servers. What IP range do teamviewer servers use?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean which *ports*?

`"In general, TeamViewer will always work if surfing on the Internet is possible. Hence, no firewall configuration is required. As an alternative to port 80 HTTP, port 443 HTTPs is also being checked. In addition, it is also possible to open only port 5938 TCP on the outgoing side. Data traffic should then be able to pass through on this port without any problems."`
- http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer.aspx

Comment: Actually I'm planning on using port 5983 TCP. right now my firewall allows no incoming traffic but all outbound traffic is allowed. I want to narrow that outbound traffic to only access the teamviewer server(s)to open up remote control access. Don't want any other outbound access allowed (internet surfing).

Comment: You want to disable all internet access including windows updates?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by opening TCP 5983.
In the firewall logs, I also see UDP on the same port and that the host tries to talk to the guest on UDP port 56764.

Before allowing 5983 I had some HTTPS connections in the log, but I have not seen them after allowing 5983.

Comment: The port is wrong. The correct is TCP/5938. https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-which-ports-are-used-by-teamviewer.aspx